# How do I get Eclipse to see Scala sources in a jar?

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

I get the following Eclipse error when browsing a binary scala jar dependency :

```
Source not found

The source attachment does not contain the source for the file Http.class
You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attached Source below
```

The source attachment is a jar file containing the .scala source files, and clicking the button and re-navigating to the jar does nothing. Is there a way to get it to work?

Incidentally, this is a dependency brought in by using the SBT eclipse plugin, using the withSources() dependency

Comment: why not just extract the jar?

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. It looks like Eclipse can't identify the trait in the scala file whatever I do.

Comment: did you match your package structure with your directory structure as required in java?

Comment: Yes that's it! Post it as an answer & I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure to match your package structure with your directory structure as required in java.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed scala IDE for Eclipse Source Feature.And then you can 
attach sources to scala-library in eclipse for scala projects
[install scala IDE for Eclipse Source Feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnzUh.png)